# Deleting a few files in .git/logs/refs/remotes/ directory

Tags: git

There are 3 empty files (with names of branches apparently) in .git/logs/refs/remotes/ directory that I want to delete, to make a repository portable to Windows (because their file names are colliding with 3 others that differ in case).

Will I lose anything with this operation? Will it affect anything in my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you will not lose anything, especially since the files are empty.

---

Files under `.git/logs` store the reflog for each named ref -- the output of `git reflog branch-name` or `git reflog origin/branch` come from these files.

They will be recreated if needed, and the only impact you can have is if you delete a non empty reflog.

---

Note that the most important of these reflog file is arguably `.git/logs/HEAD`, and I would strongly advise to *keep* that one and not delete it.

`.git/logs/stash` also has a role : it contains the data for `git stash list`.